# Reflecting variable to View in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, asyncstorage

I'm new in `React native` and I know this common to ask but I've been confused on how can I reflect varible to my view text based on the `AsyncStorage` variable , I've used `AsyncStorage` but it returns me an error

Error: `Can't find variable:username`

I have this

```
import React, {useContext,useState} from 'react';
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  ImageBackground,
} from 'react-native';
import {AuthContext} from '../navigation/AuthProvider';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';


const LoginScreen = ({navigation}) => {

  const {googleLogin} = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [state, setState] = useState(username);
  AsyncStorage.getItem('userPrivilege').then((variable) => {
    if (variable != null) {
      console.log("hoy");
      console.log(variable);
      setState({username: variable})   
    }
  }); 
  return (
    <View >
      <ImageBackground source={require('../assets/images/launch_screen.png')} style= {styles.backgroundImage}   >
        <Text>{state.username}</Text>
    </ImageBackground>
    </View>
    
  );
};
```

**Update**

[image]

It works now but when I tried to print value through a console it has infinite value in my console, do you know what the problem is?

Comment: Where you have the console log for the variable - save the value to a state. Then in the Text element below, refer to it as {{myVariable}}

Comment: @Aleksandar Zoric Thanks for your response I updated my code above I used useState but it returns me an error , need help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error comes from an misunderstanding about how `useState` works.

The value from the `useState`, `state` in your case takes the type of what you put inside, in your case `username` in a `string` or `undefined` **at the begging**.

So `state` is not an `object` **at the begging**.

To fix your error, you can initialize your state to

```
const [state, setState] = useState({username: ''});
```

**Update** but it gets me an **error**

```
Objects are not valid as a React child(Found: object with keys {username}).If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

**Code**

```
const [state, setState] = useState({username: ''});

AsyncStorage.getItem('userPrivilege').then((variable) => {
    if (variable != null) {
       setState({username: variable}) 
    }
}

return (
    <View>
       <Text>{state}</Text>
    </View>
     );
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response but it gives me an error

Comment: add this also `{state?.username}`

Comment: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qewaE.png)  it works now but I have infinite data when I tried to print the value of `asyncStorage` in my loginScreen do you know what the problem is? or should I ignore this?  I used `googleSignIn`  need help

Comment: Wrap your call to Async Storage inside a `useEffect` with empty array dependencies